# iOS container view controller - Why does transitionFromViewController need the fromViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

When using custom container view controller, I don't quite understand why the presenting view controller needs to specify the from, because being the container class, it should already know what's in the view hierarchy, no?

[transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Container view controllers sometimes need to put the views of the contained controllers into **specific subviews** of their own view. (For example, a SplitViewController reimplementation might have left and right positioning views holding the master and detail controller views respectively.) Providing the fromViewController tells UIViewController where in the view hierarchy the new controller's view should be inserted, and also which specific view should be removed after the animation.

(contrary to another answer, the *frames* of the views aren't set for you at all. You do that, before the call, and in the animation block. The "[Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)" system guide in the docs has a pretty good example.)

As it happens, actually using `transitionFromViewController:...` appears to be optional. You can manage your view hierarchy manually, with or without animations, and it works fine. I'm still forming my opinions, but I think I prefer to do it manually, to more easily handle cases where one of the VCs is nil.

Answer (score 0):

This is done this way to allow you to have a view controller that has views with viewControllers in it. The from defines the originating view controller and gives the system the ability to position the animations appropriately.

Imaging you had a view with 4 views in it like tiles. the main view controller can consecutively call this on its "child" view controllers and with the from -> to specification, it won't make the assumption that the caller is the from viewController.